# Why am I loosing a row and a column in MATLAB slice plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a 3D volume in MATLAB. I am using the slice command.

```
a(:,:,1)=[1,2; 3,4];
a(:,:,2)=[5,6; 9,8];
figure;
slice (a,0,0,1);
hold on
slice (a,0,0,2);
```

The figure I get has just one square (pixel). I am expecting 4 squares. How do I plot this? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `slice (a,1,0,0);` and `slice (a,2,0,0);` plus those you have plotted?

Comment: That will form a cube and I will not be able to see the surface inside.

Comment: You're plotting in 3-D. You need to think in terms of vertices instead of pixels. It's not clear exactly what you're expecting.

Comment: Use `alpha`, that will help you see inside! (like `alpha(.5)`)

Comment: Thanks :-) that was helpful. But my original question is still unresolved. Why do I not see 4 squares on each plane?

Comment: @horchler - sorry did not see your comment earlier. And eventually I came to the same conclusion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant part of [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html):

> slice(V,sx,sy,sz) draws slices along the x, y, z directions in the volume V at the points in the vectors sx, sy, and sz. V is an m-by-n-by-p volume array containing data values at the default location X = 1:n, Y = 1:m, Z = 1:p. Each element in the vectors sx, sy, and sz defines a slice plane in the x-, y-, or z-axis direction.

So, your command `slice (a,0,0,1);` is asking Matlab to produce **three** slices of the cube [1,2]×[1,2]×[1,2] (colored according to the values of your `a` array), by the following planes

- x=0 plane (shown as empty square since it's outside of the cube)
- y=0 plane (same story)
- z=1 plane (dark blue square).

You could have avoided the extraneous x=0 and y=0 slices with `slice(a,[],[],1)`. Also,

- `slice(a,[],[],[1,2])` would give you top and bottom
- `slice(a,[],[1,2],[])` would give two vertical sides
- `slice(a,[1,2],[],[])` would give two other vertical sides

Or you could just get all six at once with `slice(a,[1,2],[1,2],[1,2])`. If you don't want, e.g., top and bottom slices, then `slice(a,[1,2],[1,2],[])`.

Note that the entries of `a` are not coordinates, they are understood as values of a function of three variables, and are represented by colors.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But now I am still stuck with a figure that looks like this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/dycMg.png I am beginning to think that slice plots the values at the vertices and the colour of the surface is a gradient between the two values.

Comment: If you want four squares, including those two, use `slice(a,[],[1,2],[1,2])` or `slice(a,[1,2],[],[1,2])`. If you want more _horizontal_ squares, use `slice(a,[],[],[1:0.5:2])`, for example. As I wrote above, the color is determined by the values you put into the array a. If your array was all-ones, you would have the same color everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. My actual array is 6x6x6. The 2x2x2 was just a simplified example for posting here. [1:0.5:2] will probably not work. Perhaps i'll use [1:(1/6):6] and try.